# weird syntax error in ocaml

Tags: string, parsing, pattern-matching, ocaml

hey I'm just starting using Ocaml, and i got this weird Syntax error that i can't understand!
here's my program:

```
let out x = Printf.printf " %s \n" x 
let _ = try
  while true do
    let line = input_line stdin in 
     begin
    match (Str.split (Str.regexp " ") line) with
            ["commit";code] -> out code;
            | ["diff"; _; before; after] -> out before;
        out after;
          let rec f (xpath: string list) : ( string list ) =
           (match  Str.split (Str.regexp "/") xpath  with 
                     | _ ::rest -> out (String.concat "/" rest)
                     | _ -> []
           )
            | _ -> ()
     end
   done
with
  End_of_file -> ()
```

Comment: You need to do some work to get helpful answers. At the very least, you should supply the error message that you saw. It would also be good to reduce the code to the smallest that shows the problem. (Sometimes this lets you figure it out yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do with

```
let rec f (xpath: string list) : ( string list ) =
       (match  Str.split (Str.regexp "/") xpath  with 
                 | _ ::rest -> out (String.concat "/" rest)
                 | _ -> []
       )
```

this block of code has nothing to do do with the rest of your code.

Remove it and your code will be syntactically correct.